# The height of inner divs in a flexbox child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

We've been looking all over the web, but can't find a solution to a seemingly unsolvable problem basically we've got two divs who need to be equal in height. In them we've got multiple other divs who need to scale in height with them.
We tried 100% height, flexbox, inherit, overflow hidden and other things we could think of. To no avail.

This is a simplistic view of what we've got:

```css
.col-sm-12 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex
}
.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  flex: 1;
}
.c1 {
}
.c2 {
  padding: 20px;
}
.c3 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="c1">
        <div class="c2">
          <div class="image">

          </div>
          <div class="c3">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean consectetur dui quis arcu varius, sit amet consectetur risus auctor. Nulla id mattis ligula. Aliquam euismod dui et viverra ultrices. Praesent eget quam quam. Aenean sit amet lectus et leo ultrices sodales id sed nulla. Proin fringilla, dui vitae tincidunt tincidunt, nisi tellus efficitur lacus, ac facilisis libero elit ut tellus. In finibus tortor leo, hendrerit sagittis libero maximus sed. Sed rhoncus maximus odio, nec vestibulum enim fringilla ac. Nulla faucibus, justo nec fermentum blandit, est nisl eleifend purus, non pretium orci sapien at eros. Fusce non laoreet augue. Aenean ac eros augue. Sed sit amet enim sit amet lorem finibus volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris placerat, diam sed vulputate aliquet, augue erat luctus massa, molestie egestas diam metus at dolor. Vivamus a metus vitae magna dignissim pulvinar.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="c1">
        <div class="c2">
          <div class="image">

          </div>
          <div class="c3">
            <p>
              Etiam id ullamcorper augue, a pharetra nisi. Sed justo enim, malesuada elementum erat non, vehicula varius turpis. Sed quis scelerisque eros, in vestibulum mi. Maecenas et consectetur risus, sed sagittis ex. Aliquam vestibulum fermentum hendrerit. Nulla eget hendrerit purus. Suspendisse commodo vel tortor ut sollicitudin.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can we get the two boxes below the image to equal height?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why not assign a height to them?

Comment: are the images going to be the same aspect ratio - if so then this would be very simple, if not you would need to use a bit of js

Comment: Set a equal height to the section where you want

Comment: @ChrisLi Because I've got about three rows of these and they all have different heights and need to be fully responsive and stay the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no CSS method of equalising heights of elements that do not share a parent. If the top image is **always the same height between columns** you can use flexbox to expand the smaller/shorter column though.

```css
.col-sm-12 {
  display: flex;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.c1 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.c2 {
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.c3 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="c1">
      <div class="c2">
        <div class="image">

        </div>
        <div class="c3">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean consectetur dui quis arcu varius, sit amet consectetur risus auctor. Nulla id mattis ligula. Aliquam euismod dui et viverra ultrices. Praesent eget quam quam. Aenean sit amet lectus et leo
            ultrices sodales id sed nulla. Proin fringilla, dui vitae tincidunt tincidunt, nisi tellus efficitur lacus, ac facilisis libero elit ut tellus. In finibus tortor leo, hendrerit sagittis libero maximus sed. Sed rhoncus maximus odio, nec vestibulum
            enim fringilla ac. Nulla faucibus, justo nec fermentum blandit, est nisl eleifend purus, non pretium orci sapien at eros. Fusce non laoreet augue. Aenean ac eros augue. Sed sit amet enim sit amet lorem finibus volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris placerat, diam sed vulputate aliquet, augue erat luctus massa, molestie egestas diam metus at dolor. Vivamus a metus vitae magna dignissim pulvinar.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="c1">
      <div class="c2">
        <div class="image">

        </div>
        <div class="c3">
          <p>
            Etiam id ullamcorper augue, a pharetra nisi. Sed justo enim, malesuada elementum erat non, vehicula varius turpis. Sed quis scelerisque eros, in vestibulum mi. Maecenas et consectetur risus, sed sagittis ex. Aliquam vestibulum fermentum hendrerit. Nulla
            eget hendrerit purus. Suspendisse commodo vel tortor ut sollicitudin.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It didn't occur to us to use flexboxes on every div. Instead we tried to use 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

Just use inline-style on the text `div` tags:

```
style="height:30em;overflow:scroll"
```

lol. There might be a lot of new, flashy and sexy frameworks & technologies out there (which I really like), but sometimes going back to the old school methods is a lot simpler and more efficient.